# SKCalloutView only shows up at zoom level 5

Tags: android, skmaps

The minimum zoom level for my annotations is set to 1. However, callout views only start showing up after zoom level 5 and above.

Is there a setting I've missed?

Comment: Can you please add the code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

In iOS, you need to set the annotationTapZoomLimit setting of the map to 0.

So,

```
mapView.settings.annotationTapZoomLimit = 0;
```

It solved my problem!